# Dropping df 's rows inside an iterrows() function does'nt work

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe df1 and I want to create a new df2 with columns created from df1 's rows values :

```
    DAT_RUN DAT_FORECAST    LIB_SOURCE  TEMPERATURE_PREDITE NUM_DEVICE_ID_VISIOGREEN    DIFF_HOURS  TEMPERATURE_OBSERVEE    MonthNumber origine
0   2020-08-11  2020-08-11  arome_001   22.365373   20002748    0.0 22.51   8   Visiogreen
1   2020-08-11  2020-08-11  arpege_01   23.280028   20002748    0.0 22.51   8   Visiogreen
```

For example, for the first above 2 rows, I want only 1 row with news columns as:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
1) I iterate on each row of the df with iterrows() function:
2) For each row, I'm looking for identicals rows based on columns conditions
3) After, I drop rows:
    
print("START")

new_sorted_fpm_dsczd_sencrop_fpm_dsczd_fact_visiogreen = sorted_fpm_dsczd_sencrop_fpm_dsczd_fact_visiogreen.copy()

final_df = pd.DataFrame()

for index1, row1 in new_sorted_fpm_dsczd_sencrop_fpm_dsczd_fact_visiogreen.iterrows():
    
    print(f"""We manage : {row1['DAT_RUN']}, {row1['DAT_FORECAST']}, {row1['LIB_SOURCE']}, {row1['NUM_DEVICE_ID_VISIOGREEN']}, {row1['DIFF_HOURS']}, {row1['TEMPERATURE_OBSERVEE']}, {row1['TEMPERATURE_PREDITE']}, {row1['origine']}""")
    
    d = {'DAT_RUN'              : row1['DAT_RUN'],
         'DAT_FORECAST'         : row1['DAT_FORECAST'],
         'DIFF_HOURS'           : row1['DIFF_HOURS'],
         'TEMPERATURE_OBSERVEE' : row1['TEMPERATURE_OBSERVEE'],
         'MonthNumber'          : row1['MonthNumber']
        }
    
    df_temp = new_sorted_fpm_dsczd_sencrop_fpm_dsczd_fact_visiogreen[(new_sorted_fpm_dsczd_sencrop_fpm_dsczd_fact_visiogreen['DAT_RUN'] == row1['DAT_RUN']) 
                                                                   & (new_sorted_fpm_dsczd_sencrop_fpm_dsczd_fact_visiogreen['DAT_FORECAST'] == row1['DAT_FORECAST'])
                                                                   & (new_sorted_fpm_dsczd_sencrop_fpm_dsczd_fact_visiogreen['NUM_DEVICE_ID_VISIOGREEN'] == row1['NUM_DEVICE_ID_VISIOGREEN'])
                                                                   & (new_sorted_fpm_dsczd_sencrop_fpm_dsczd_fact_visiogreen['DIFF_HOURS'] == row1['DIFF_HOURS'])
                                                                   & (new_sorted_fpm_dsczd_sencrop_fpm_dsczd_fact_visiogreen['TEMPERATURE_OBSERVEE'] == row1['TEMPERATURE_OBSERVEE'])
                                                                   & (new_sorted_fpm_dsczd_sencrop_fpm_dsczd_fact_visiogreen['origine'] == row1['origine'])]
    # Récupération des index
    index_names = df_temp.index
    
    #print(f"""Il y a {df_temp.shape[0]} enregistrements identiques""")
    
    for index2, row2 in df_temp.iterrows():
        print(f"""Which have identicals: {row2['DAT_RUN']}, {row2['DAT_FORECAST']}, {row2['DIFF_HOURS']}, {row2['LIB_SOURCE']}, {row2['NUM_DEVICE_ID_VISIOGREEN']},  {row2['TEMPERATURE_OBSERVEE']},  {row2['TEMPERATURE_PREDITE']}, {row2['origine']}""")
            
        if row2['LIB_SOURCE'] == 'arome_001':
            coldfname = 'T_AROME'
        else:
            if row2['LIB_SOURCE'] == 'arpege_01':
                coldfname = 'T_ARPEGE'
            else:
                if row2['LIB_SOURCE'] == 'gfs_025':
                    coldfname = 'T_GFS'
                else:
                    print("Attention: il n'y a pas dans ce bloc de prévisions arome, arpege ou GFS")
        d.update([(coldfname, row1['TEMPERATURE_PREDITE'])])
        
    final_df = final_df.append(d, ignore_index=True)
    
    # Suppression des lignes traitées
    print(f"""We drop {len(index_names)} enregistrements identiques""")
    
    #new_sorted_fpm_dsczd_sencrop_fpm_dsczd_fact_visiogreen.drop(index1, inplace = True)
    new_sorted_fpm_dsczd_sencrop_fpm_dsczd_fact_visiogreen.drop(index_names, inplace = True)
  
print("END")
```

Output:

```
START
We manage : 2020-08-11 00:00:00, 2020-08-11 00:00:00, arome_001, 20002748, 0.0, 22.509999999999998, 22.3653728369278, Visiogreen
Which have identicals: 2020-08-11 00:00:00, 2020-08-11 00:00:00, 0.0, arome_001, 20002748,  22.509999999999998,  22.3653728369278, Visiogreen
Which have identicals: 2020-08-11 00:00:00, 2020-08-11 00:00:00, 0.0, arpege_01, 20002748,  22.509999999999998,  23.2800282137495, Visiogreen
We drop 2 enregistrements identiques
We manage : 2020-08-11 00:00:00, 2020-08-11 00:00:00, arpege_01, 20002748, 0.0, 22.509999999999998, 23.2800282137495, Visiogreen
We drop 0 enregistrements identiques
END
```

I have 2 problems in final_df:

```
 DAT_RUN    DAT_FORECAST    DIFF_HOURS  TEMPERATURE_OBSERVEE    MonthNumber T_AROME T_ARPEGE
0   2020-08-11  2020-08-11  0.0 22.51   8.0 22.365373   22.365373
1   2020-08-11  2020-08-11  0.0 22.51   8.0 NaN NaN
```

1. a second line is created : I think that iterrows() does not well managed rows dropped inside loop !?
2. and forecast value is the same in the 2 columns

Théo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a second line is created : I think that iterrows() does not well managed rows dropped inside loop !?

Generally speaking, trying to modify an index (or any structure) in an iterative way is a risky exercise, as the structure will change from iteration to iteration, and references won't stay consistent. Now you have two nested loops in your code, and three DataFrames, which makes it all the more complicated.

I'd rather suggest to change your approach and that you take advantage of the grouping possibilities of DataFrames.

```py
import numpy as np

def sum_and_keep_nans(s: pd.Series):
    """
    Aggregation function that returns NaN if ALL values in the Series are NaN, 
    or the sum of the Series values otherwise.
    """
    if s.isna().all():
        return np.nan
    return s.sum()

# From your code, I understand you want to keep the original df, so we make a copy
final_df = sorted_fpm_dsczd_sencrop_fpm_dsczd_fact_visiogreen.copy()

# Now let's create the new columns. For each, we use "LIB_SOURCE" as a filter to 
# report 'TEMPERATURE_PREDITE', so values will be either that or NaN
final_df['T_AROME'] = final_df['TEMPERATURE_PREDITE'][final_df['LIB_SOURCE'] == 'arome_001']
final_df['T_ARPEGE'] = final_df['TEMPERATURE_PREDITE'][final_df['LIB_SOURCE'] == 'arpege_01']
final_df['T_GFS'] = final_df['TEMPERATURE_PREDITE'][final_df['LIB_SOURCE'] == 'gfs_025']

# Let's drop those, we don't need them anymore
final_df.drop(['TEMPERATURE_PREDITE', 'LIB_SOURCE'], axis=1, inplace=True)

# Now we have 3 columns, with either zeros or 'TEMPERATURE_PREDITE' as a value,
# we're going to sum them for each set of identical values in the other columns
columns_to_sum = ['T_AROME', 'T_ARPEGE', 'T_GFS']
# we define the grouping to apply the summation as all non-summed columns
columns_to_group = list(final_df.columns.drop(columns_to_sum))

# finally, we group by date, device..., use our custom aggregation function, and 
# we reset the index to keep the df columns
final_df = final_df.groupby(columns_to_group)[columns_to_sum].agg(sum_and_keep_nans).reset_index()
```

Ouput:

```sh
      DAT_RUN DAT_FORECAST  NUM_DEVICE_ID_VISIOGREEN  DIFF_HOURS  TEMPERATURE_OBSERVEE  MonthNumber     origine    T_AROME   T_ARPEGE  T_GFS
0  2020-08-11   2020-08-11                  20002748         0.0                 22.51            8  Visiogreen  22.365373  23.280028    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for this code more elegant than mine. I tested it on the first 100 records: with my code after removing duplicates there are only 53 lines while with yours it keeps 100 records.

Comment: `groupby` should deduplicate the rows. I tested it with your 2-row example and it does return only one record in `final_df`. Is there a column in your data that was not present in the example, like a unique identifier?

Comment: Wouah your code works fine now and it is more elegant and also  quicker  than mine! Any idea to change forecast value 0 to NAN rather? Because when there is no value, 0 could be a forecast value.

Comment: @Theo75 I completely missed the fact that 0.0 could be a valid forecast, you're right to point it out. I edited my answer so that it covers this case. Now it will report 0.0 if such a temperature was forecasted, and NaN in the other cases.

Comment: Sorry thanks for your works but I have a pb of index on the whole data that you don't have with only 2 rows: " ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis" error on instruction : "df['T_AROME']  = df['TEMPERATURE_PREDITE'][df['LIB_SOURCE'] == 'arome_001']" and probably for the follows.

Comment: @Theo75 it might come from a prior manipulation of the df, or the way you constructed it. Did you per chance create df by concatenating several other DataFrames? If so, try to concatenate using the option `ignore_index=True`. Alternatively, you might want to reset the index just before the lines raising this error, with `df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`